# The horizontal velocity $v$ that must be given to the mass $m$ to rotate the pendulum $90$ degrees

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

> A compound pendulum consists of a uniform rod of length $L$ of negligible mass. A body of mass $m$ is fixed at the lower end and a body of mass $2m$ is fixed exactly in the middle of the rod. The horizontal velocity $v$ that must be given to the mass $m$ to rotate the pendulum $90$ degrees is__________?

So essentially at the moment I'm aware of the 'official' solution (which is to say the body of mass $2m$ has a velocity of $\frac{v}{2}$ and work from there). I was just wondering if I can solve this using centre of mass. So far what I have is:

$CM = \frac{2}{3}L$

The rotational velocity of the whole body stays the same: $\omega = \frac{v_1}{L}$ (velocity of the bottom mass) and $\omega = \frac{v_2}{\frac{2}{3}L}$ (velocity of the centre of mass). So $v_2=\frac{2}{3}v_1$.

Then you use conservation of energy:

$\frac{1}{2}(3m)(\frac{2}{3}v)^2 = (3m)(g)(\frac{2}{3}L)$

Which gives the final answer of $(3gL)^\frac{1}{2}$ but the actual answer is $(\frac{8gL}{3})^\frac{1}{2}$. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is not the full kinetic energy.

Consider putting a camera always focused on the rod's center of mass. It would see the rod rotating about that center with angular frequency $\omega$. As such, it has additional kinetic energy. If the moment of inertia of the rod is $I$ about its center of mass, we have an extra kinetic energy

$$\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2.$$

Since the velocity is then associated with more kinetic energy, the minimum velocity becomes smaller than your original estimate of $\sqrt{3gL}$